# Inverse of Normal Distribution CDF incorrect for large value?

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, special-functions, inverse

I have a function `F` which is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. The inverse of `F` should be infinity at 1. However, I got 8.52 for below:

```
F[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
N@InverseFunction[F[#] &][1/2/0.5]
```

If I amend my code to `N@InverseFunction[F[#] &][1]`, the output would even give me a complex number.

Why is the result of `1` different to `1/2/0.5`?

How can I force it to produce the correct result?

Comment: Actually, why are you not using `InverseCDF[]` or `Quantile[]`? `InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1/2/0.5]`

Comment: Thanks. It works well.